# COPY command not working as expected in multistage Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

## Stage 1:

```
FROM node:10.23.0-alpine as react
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm run build
```

## Stage2:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine3.7 AS release  
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app
# In the below line only the contents of the build folder is been copied and not the folder itself
COPY --from=react /app/build ./
```

From the above Dockerfile I am trying to copy the build folder from stage 1 to python image in stage 2. Only the contents of the build folder is been copied and not the complete folder

Comment: Copy it to a directory, `COPY --from=react /app/build ./build`. Read https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy.

Comment: no, its not working. I tried ```COPY --from=react /app/build ./build```

Comment: What do you mean *"not working"*. What happens, then? If doing it the right way doesn't work ask about *that*, but what you've shown *is* behaving as expected.

Comment: All the contents inside the build folder is getting copied.. but the build folder is not present inside the pod. I tried kubectl exec to the pod

Comment: OK I deleted all previous images and tried once again. It started working. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a folder where you want to copy it

`COPY --from=react /app/build ./new_directory`